# Users hasMany Adresses and Users hasOne MainAdresse with custom Auth login

Tags: authentication, cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.0

My Users can have many Addresses so I used hasMany association. When they log in, it works perfectly and I can access thoses Addresses. I tried to define a MainAddress that will be used as default, but when they log in my custom Auth finder ignore my hasOne association and doesn't return any error.

```
// in UserTable.php
$this->hasMany('Addresses', [
    'className' => 'Addresses',
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
]);

$this->hasOne('MainAddress', [
    'className' => 'Addresses',
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
    'conditions' => ['is_main' => true]
]);

// ...
public function findAuth(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options)
{
     $query
     ->select(['id', 'email', 'password'])
     ->contain(['Addresses', 'MainAddress']);

     return $query;
}
```

I still get all the Addresses with `$_user->addresses`, but the Main one is not listed in my session (there is no `$_user->main_address`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused due to the `select()` you have. You need to include the fields of hasOne associated table (since it does a join) also in the list.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot ! But I don't get why it was working with "hasMany" and not with "hasOne".

Comment: Because the hasMany associated records as fetched using a separate query and the select() done for primary query doesn't affect it.